# C++ Error "expected an unqualified id before ')' token" (line 1)

Tags: c++

So I am really new to C++ so forgive me for amateur code. I am trying to make a code that acts like a mini-SIRI that incorporates inheritance classes and header files but I am currently getting a weird error in my header file.

Here is my code in each file

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JARVIS.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string command;
bool jarvis_running = false;
cout << "J.A.R.V.I.S" << endl;
cout << "Give a command from the list of commands available." << endl;
cin >> command;

if (command == "-h")
    {
    jarvis_running = true;
    cout << "The available commands are: math" << endl;
    }

if (command = "math")
    {
    jarvis_running = true;
    math ma;
    }


if (jarvis_running == false)
    {
    cout << "That command was not valid" << endl;
    cout << "Type '-h' if you need to know the available commands." << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

*JarvisFunctions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "JARVIS.h"

using namespace std;

int math()
{
    cout << "(A)ddition, (S)ubtraction, (M)ultiplication, or (D)ivision?" << endl;
    cin >> mathCommand;

    if (mathCommand == "A")
        {
        cout << "input the two integers you are adding" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        ma.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        addition add;
        }


    else if(mathCommand == "S")
        {
        cout << "input the two integers you are subtracting" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        ma.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        subtraction sub;
        }

    else if(mathCommand == "M")
        {
        cout << "input the two integers you are multiplying" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        ma.setValue(integer1, integer2);
        mulitplication multi;
        }

    else if(mathCommand == "D")
        {
        cout << "input the two integers you are dividing" << endl;
        cin >> integer1 >> integer2;

        ma.setValues(integer1, integer2);
        divions div;
        }

    else
        {
        cout << "you did not input the right fuctions, either use A, S, M, or D" << endl;
        }
}
```

JARVIS.h

```
#ifndef JARVIS_H
#define JARVIS_H

class math
    {
    private:
    int val1;
    int val2;

    public:

    math()
    {
    cout<<"calling math constructor"<<endl;
    }

    void setValues (int a, int b){
        int a = val1;
        int b = val2;
    }

    ~math()
    {
     cout<<"calling math deconstructor"<<endl;   
    }

}

class addition:public math
{
    int finalVal = val1 + val2;
    return finalVal;
};

class subtraction:public math
{
    int finalVal = val1 - val2;
    return finalVal;
};

class multiplication:public math
{
    int finalVal = val1 * val2;
    return finalVal;
};

class division:public math
{
    int finalVal = val1 / val2;
    return finalVal;
};

#endif  //JARVIS_H
```

I'm pretty sure there's still a lot wrong with the class and how I call them but for now I am not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: class `math` is missing its closing semi-colon after the closing `}`. And none of the derivatives of `math` are correct. You're treating them like they're functions; not classes.

Comment: It would be helpful with full compiler log and the command you use to compile your program, it looks like a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: class `addition` isn't correct either.

Comment: you're missing a log of `;` after `class X {}`. It should be `class X {};`

Comment: And your assignments of members `a` and `b` are written the wrong way around.

Comment: @gauteh I am using Code Blocks through Oracle Virtual Machine. My error log is here:                                         ||=== Build: Debug in JARVIS (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/user/Dropbox/Lecture36CompilationAndMemory/JARVIS/JARVIS.h|1|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit questions posted near semester-end before the holidays are like a box of chocolates. Never know what you're gonna get. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig We always know exactly what we're gonna get :(

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place a semicolon after the closing brace of the class math definition.

Also definitions like this

```
class addition:public math
{
    int finalVal = val1 + val2;
    return finalVal;
};
```

are invalid in C++. A class is not a function and its definition may not contain return statement.

Also there is no any sense to define a local object in a block scope that is not used as in this if statement

```
if (command == "math")
    {
    jarvis_running = true;
    math ma;
    }
```

Object ma will not exist outside the compound statement of the if.

Or where is mathCommand defined that used in statement

```
cin >> mathCommand;
```

Or instead of

```
void setValues (int a, int b){
    int a = val1;
    int b = val2;
}
```

I think you mean

```
void setValues (int a, int b){
    val1 = a;
    val2 = b;
}
```

So your program is entirely wrong. It has plenty of errors so there is no sense to discuss your code. At first you should write more or less valid C++ code.

Comment: And there is no class called `divions`, yet it is used in `main()`. `math::setValues` will won't compile, as it is redeclaring `a` and `b` in the same scope as the parameters. And as lightness pointed out, even if it did compile it is still wrong, as the assignments are in the wrong direction, using non-initialized content from `val1` and `val2`.

Comment: ok, I fixed the semicolons. I seem to still be getting the same error when I compile the code. Yeah I should have realized the class wouldn't work that way. I think I can still add a function within the class that will do the simple addition right? Can I not run a function through an if statement? I defined mathCommand now. Thank you for the help, I'm aware its flooded with bugs and I want to debug it but this current error seems to hold back the other errors from showing. It says there's only 1 error when I know there's way more than that.

Comment: I also reversed a and b and fixed the class divions, it was misspelled.